# method to update table based on function output

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using an access function that loops through multiple record sets using case select statements and displays rows of strings in the VBA immediate window.

Can anyone suggest how I can learn about methods that might be used to update a table with the results that are currently displayed in the VBA immediate window?

So far, my searches have suggested that `DoCmd.SQL` might work.

```
    Case Is = "1"                    ' 1 bottle
        Debug.Print rsWCol!r4_wcol_outstring & rsBottl!bottleoutstring

        displays the string below in the immediate window:

        R41602T50 1  00   62  710 C 1120   9800 550     1 00S #135                     0
```

I'd like to be able to use something like the following

```
Dim writeRecSQL As String ' used to append records to a temp table
writeRecSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_R_export_TEMP ( R_str ) select rsWCol!r4_wcol_outstring & rsBottl!bottleoutstring;" 


        Case Is = "1"                    ' 1 bottle
        ' Debug.Print rsWCol!r4_wcol_outstring & rsBottl!bottleoutstring
        DoCmd.RunSQL writeRecSQL
```

The select part of my SQL statement does not seem to be getting values. 
I understand that, normally, it might be something like `select fieldX from tablex`
And that my statement is more like: `select rs!foo`

An *'Enter Parameter Value'* message box is raised asking for the value of *r4_wcol_outstring*

(Following the SELECT in my SQL with a `FROM` raises VB `"Run-time error '3134' syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."`)

I could use some advice or an example of how write an SQL statement that will my record set parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

Good place to start is Microsoft's site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx

But if you just want to insert values from a record you just retrieved into another table
try wrapping fields in escaped double quotes and concetanting the values outside the hardcoded string.

**As in:**
`writeRecSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_R_export_TEMP ( [R_str] ) VALUES (""" & rsWCol!r4_wcol_outstring & rsBottl!bottleoutstring & """);"`

Besides `Docmd.RunSQL`, you can also look at `CurrentDB.Execute` and predefined parameter queries using the Querydefs object

Comment: Your suggestion: "wrapping fields in escaped double quotes and concatenating the values outside the hard coded string" and example solves my problem and gets the job done beautifully.

Comment: Thanks - I see you're a new poster. If it was the answer that solved your issue or was helpful please mark it as such. That's the little reward we get from trying to help. You can do similar upvoting for other questions and answers you find intriguing or useful on this site